# Best way to upload large JSON to server?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to upload large (5-10 mb) json files to server?

I'm newbie, trying to do something like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = 'data=' + encodeURIComponent(myJSON);
request.open("POST", website, true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.send(data);
```

Mostly it works, but sometimes server not receive post request, specially when my network speed is low.

Is there any **safe** & **reliable** way to send large json files to server?

Comment: Use `fetch()` with a `FormData` with a `Blob` of your JSON data. Your backend must be able to receive multipart form data.

Comment: Oh, i can't make it work right way :( I'm rly newbie, any example would be much appreciated <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment

> Use `fetch()` with a `FormData` with a `Blob` of your JSON data. Your backend must be able to receive multipart form data.

something like this might be the minimal implementation of just that.

```
const data = new FormData();
const jsonBlob = new Blob([myJSON], {type: "application/json"});
data.append("data", jsonBlob);
fetch(website, {
  method: "POST",
  body: data,
}).then(resp => {
  if(!resp.ok) {
    const err = new Error("Response wasn't okay");
    err.resp = resp;
    throw err;
  }
  console.log("Okay!");
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```