# How to receive Fetch() POST in php?

Tags: javascript, php

So i got this POST json method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65363010/best-way-to-upload-large-json-to-server), but can't understand how to get my json data

It's packed in BLOB which is packed in FormData

How to receive such POST in php? *(and convert this FormData(Blob) back to json?)*

JS

```
        const data = new FormData();
        const jsonBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(myJSON)], {type: "application/json"});
        data.append("data", jsonBlob);
        fetch(website,{
            method: "POST",
            body: data,
        }).then(resp=>{
            if(!resp.ok){
                const err = new Error("Error response");
                err.resp = resp;
                throw err;
            }
            console.log("OK");
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.error(err);
        })
```

I'm big noobo, so i can't even receive it

Seems like it works differently with `fetch()`

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){

}
```

Comment: `err.resp = response` where is `response` declared? you may want to read [Using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: My bad, forgot to change it back. Fetch() works perfect, i just can't imagine how to receive it in php. Seems like it's impossible to separate POST requests if using Fetch(). Like $_POST['data'], $_POST['info'] etc.

Comment: A Blob mimics  a file being sent. So on the server side, you have to treat it like a file. `if (isset($_FILES['data'])) { $json = file_get_contents($_FILES['data']['tmp_name']);  $arr = json_decode($json, true);  var_dump($arr); }` (In the example here, `var_dump` will echo the structure of the Array, with types and everything, just for testing that you receive the JSON you expect)

Comment: try this to see what you posted. `var_dump($_POST); exit;`

Comment: @blex it works thank you <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way to send a JSON to server is to simply send it as the POST request body. There is no need to wrap it like a file. For example,

```js
var myJSON = {
    hello: 'world',
    foo: 'bar',
};
fetch(website, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(myJSON),
})
```

On server side, your message will be readable through [the "php://input" stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php). You can read it like an ordinary file:

```php
$request_raw = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_object = json_decode($request_raw);
```

You can save the below code as a PHP file and test it yourself. On load, it would send itself another POST reqeust, parse it as key-value pairs, return it to your browser and show it:

```php
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $request_raw = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $request = json_decode($request_raw);
        foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
                echo "{$key}: {$value}\n";
        }
        exit;
}

?>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
var myJSON = {
    hello: 'world',
    foo: 'bar',
};
const data = new FormData();
fetch(document.location.href, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(myJSON),
}).then(resp => {
    if(!resp.ok){
        const err = new Error("Error response");
        err.resp = resp;
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("OK");
    return resp.text();
}).catch(err =>{
    console.error(err);
}).then(body => {
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = body;
});
</script>
```